# TWebBrowser OpenStreetMap Geolocation denied

Tags: delphi, location, maps, openstreetmap

Delphi - Tokyo 10.2

I'm following the 'LocationDemo' example provided by Embarcadero Rad Studio
([URL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Location_Sensors_(iOS_and_Android))), I've already handle the location permission for the app but I'm not able to use 'Show my location' while browsing a map of OpenStreetMap.

When I try, I get the following error: "**Geolocation error: User denied Geolocation**".

If I use Chrome, instead of my app with the TWebBrowser component, the browser asks to allow localization. What should I do to allow my app do the same?

Edit

- Coarse location, fine location, internet are checked inside project>options>user permissions
- The URL assigned to the Navigate method of the TWebBrowser component has https as protocol

Comment: Did you set the user permissions required by your app? If not, check out http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Uses_Permissions

Comment: coarse location, fine location, internet are checked inside project>options>user permissions

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: no, I suggest to try with 10.3 Rio and enable "Maps Service" under Tools > Options > Application > Entitlement List